# PATCH and DELETE methods replace with GET in Laravel with axios

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

I create a REST API with Laravel, and use PATCH/DELETE requests. It works locally properly (WSL, nginx), but when I upload it to live server (nginx) these requests replace with a simple GET request.

POST method work properly.

```
// axios/vuejs method
api.patch('bids', this.bid).then(resp => {
    this.bid = resp.data;
});

// Route
Route::post('bids/patch', 'Api\BidsController@patchUpdate');
```

Thanks!

UPD: Thanks, I disabled a Cloudflare CDN and it works now, seems they block such requests, I wrote to support, will see.

Comment: is the *live server (nginx)* lives behind web server or CDN?

Comment: @BagusTesa yes, I use cloudflare, but can't find any settings on it. Will try to turn it off, thanks.

Comment: may i know your subscription plan? someone says that its [mostly for wordpress](https://blog.cloudflare.com/protecting-everyone-from-wordpress-content-injection/) and one can update the [Web Application Firewall rule on paid subscription](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/2704#issuecomment-328786502). sorry, i havent got myself CloudFlare to test :(